# Firebase audiences and cloud messaging not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

**Background**

I have apps I have 2 apps (Production and Staging) with the same application id `com.myapp`. They are set up as 2 separate Firebase projects
I'm switching between at runtime (admin users can switch environment in-app)

```java
FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setProjectId(isProd ?
                    getString(R.string.project_id)
                    : getString(R.string.google_project_id_staging))
            .setApplicationId(isProd ?
                    getString(R.string.google_app_id)
                    : getString(R.string.google_app_id_staging))
            .setApiKey(isProd ?
                    getString(R.string.google_api_key)
                    : getString(R.string.google_api_key_staging));

    firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, builder.build());
```

**Problems**

1. Firebase audiences showing 0 user when I filter by user id, in both Production and Staging apps
   [image]
   of course, I have `firebaseAnalytics.setUserId(userId)` in my client code
2. When I send a push notification with Cloud Messaging (FCM) it never arrived

Push notifications sent to all users have been working fine of course

3. Maybe relevant maybe not: When I run the Staging app and enabled [debug mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview), the events are reported to Debug View of the Production Firebase project, while the Debug View of the Staging project remained empty
   [image]

Could this be because my 2 apps have the same application id?

Is there anything I can do to make it work?